# bash script gives error - Argument list too long

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, centos7

I wrote a bash script and below is the sample snippet that gives "Argument list too long" error.

```
param1=$1
param2=$2
'set ${param1} "${param2}"'
```

I know the size of param2 is huge (approx 15MB and can be more as well). I read several posts about ARG_MAX and breaking down things to smaller components.

```
getconf ARG_MAX
67108864
```

Here the ARG_MAX size can easily accommodate something of size 15MB at least. So I am not sure what exactly is wrong here. Also, I am not sure if I can break this command down into smaller blocks. It's just one command which sets the whole value in one attempt.

I also ran the below command to check data limits:

```
ulimit -d
unlimited
```

Here we have unlimited size as well. Does anyone know how exactly I can bump up OS's limit to run these large commands? I am using CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) with Kernel: 4.18.9.

Comment: What is the point of setting 15MB data as positional parameter?

Comment: This is just the smallest part of the script. I am using it to run a command to set some key-value pairs in a database, where value can be large. It works when values are of smaller size though and I get the above error with large sized values.

Comment: Linux currently limits arguments to 128kiB each. ARG_MAX is for the sum of all arguments.

Comment: Consider using the pattern used by curl -d.  The -d parameter let's the user specify the body as a string or a file (-d@file).   This allows arbitrarily long input (limited by file size).

Comment: I second @Mark's suggestion -- parameters are not a good way to pass large quantities of data. Use a file, or maybe pass the data over standard input.

Comment: I wrote all contents to a file and now when I try to do the below:
<command> set ${param1} "$(< file.txt)", I still get the same error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You're still passing the actual data as an argument. What @Mark is asking for is that you make the command accept the filename. That is of course assuming that you're in control of it.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, I got it. I ended up writing a python script instead of bash. Thank you all for responses.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ :

> as additional limit since 2.6.23, one argument must not be longer than MAX_ARG_STRLEN (131072).

So you might want to try:

```
cat file.txt | set -r x
```